# Sending HTML code via JSON in Swift

Tags: php, ios, json, swift, swift2

I have to send `NSAttributedString` to mysql and be able to edit in on my website. I thought that the best idea will be converting `NSAttributedString` into array of Strings. But I have a problem with sending it. Firstly code(done thanks to one user of stack overflow:)):

```
func uploadNote(user: String, title: String, category: String, content: [String]) {
    let URL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://site/uploadNote.php")!
    let string = arrayToJSONBase64(content)

    print(string)
    let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:URL)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let bodyData = "content=\(string)"
    request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
    print("appended data to body")
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){ data, response, error in

        print("Sent request")
    }
    task.resume()

}

func arrayToJSONBase64(arr: [String]) -> String {
    let data = try?NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(arr, options: .PrettyPrinted)
    let contentJsonBase64 = data!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)

    return contentJsonBase64
}
```

And php:

```
<?php
// uploadr.php 
require_once 'log.php';
class Handler {
use Logger;

public function handleRequest($arg) {

    try  {
        $this->log(__METHOD__);
        $this->log(print_r($arg, true));
        $json = base64_decode($arg['content']);
        $this->log($json);
        // just write to a file
        file_put_contents('data.json', $json);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        $this->log('Failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
    catch( Exception $e) {

    }
}
}
$handler = new Handler();
$handler->handleRequest($_POST);
```

log.php:

```
<?php
trait Logger {
    function log($msg) {
        file_put_contents('app.log', strftime('%Y-%m-%d %T ') . $msg . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I send an array like `["one", "two", "three"]` everything is ok, it's saved in `data.json` and everything is all right. But when I try to send HTML code my `data.json` looks like this:

[MY OUTPUT](http://paste.ofcode.org/KntKEpjWiKhv53Am274YYe)

Comment: Are you targeting iOS, or Mac OS?